# Under the hood, are +myString and Number(myString) identical?

Tags: javascript

I'm not asking which one is best/nicer/whatever.

They seem to be identical in functionality:

- both return `NaN` if `myString` is not a number
- both are stricter than `parseInt()` in the sense that they don't allow "partial" numbers (`parseInt('123a')` returns `123` while `Number('123a')` returns `NaN`)

Comment: Compare https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-number-constructor-number-value, https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-unary-plus-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** The end result is the same, but the route taken there is different. But with a **HUGE** caveat!

## *Unary prefix `+` operator*

The *unary prefix `+` operator* is defined in [section 13.5.4 *Unary `+` Operator*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-unary-plus-operator) of the [ECMAScript Language Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/). In particular, its runtime semantics are defined in [sub-section 13.5.4.1 *Runtime Semantics: Evaluation*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-unary-plus-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) like this:

> 1. Let *expr* be the result of evaluating *UnaryExpression*.
> 2. Return ?ToNumber(?GetValue(*expr*)).

Where [ToNumber](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber) and [GetValue](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getvalue) are so-called [*Abstract Operations*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-algorithm-conventions-abstract-operations) defined elsewhere in the specification. You don't need to worry too much about those, all you need to know is that you can treat them kind of like functions. Their whole purpose is to avoid having to copy&paste bits of the specification to multiple places and rather be able to define an algorithm once and re-use it in different parts of the specification.

In our case, the *UnaryExpression* is a simple *string [literal](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-primary-expression-literals)* and the result of evaluating a string literal is just the primitive string value denoted by said string literal. Also, GetValue of a primitive string value is just the primitive string value itself, as you would expect.

So, for our case, this essentially just means that the *unary prefix `+` operator*, when applied to a string literal, evaluates to the result of the *abstract operation* ToNumber, applied to the string literal's primitive string value.

## `Number(value)`

The `Number(value)` function application expression is defined in [sub-section 21.1.1.1 *`Number(value)`*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor-number-value):

> When `Number` is called with argument *value*, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If value is present, then
>
>    1. Let *prim* be ?ToNumeric(*value*).
>    2. If Type(*prim*) is BigInt, let *n* be (ℝ(*prim*)).
>    3. Otherwise, let *n* be *prim*.
> 2. Else,
>
>    1. Let *n* be +0.
> 3. If NewTarget is **undefined**, return *n*.
> 4. Let *O* be ?OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(NewTarget, "**%Number.prototype%**", «[[NumberData]]»).
> 5. Set *O*.[[NumberData]] to *n*.
> 6. Return *O*.

This looks somewhat daunting at first, but we can simplify it a bit. First off, step #3 is an *early return*, and essentially means "if the `Number` function is not used as a constructor, stop the algorithm here". If you look at the [NewTarget](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-NewTarget) syntactic production, it is just the syntactic rule for the `new` operator. Since we are not using the `new` operator here, the syntactic production does not exist in the syntax tree, thus the condition in step #3 is true, and the algorithm ends here. In other words, we can cut out steps #4 and following:

> 1. If value is present, then
>
>    1. Let *prim* be ?ToNumeric(*value*).
>    2. If Type(*prim*) is BigInt, let *n* be (ℝ(*prim*)).
>    3. Otherwise, let *n* be *prim*.
> 2. Else,
>
>    1. Let *n* be +0.
> 3. Return *n*.

We also know that the value is present, because a string literal is always present, so the condition in step #1 is always true and step #2 cannot be reached:

> 1. Let *prim* be ?ToNumeric(*value*).
> 2. If Type(*prim*) is BigInt, let *n* be (ℝ(*prim*)).
> 3. Otherwise, let *n* be *prim*.
> 4. Return *n*.

If we look at the [ToNumeric](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumeric) abstract operation used in step #1 here, it looks like this:

> 1. Let *primValue* be ?ToPrimitive(*value*, `number`).
> 2. If Type(*primValue*) is BigInt, return *primValue*.
> 3. Return ?ToNumber(*primValue*).

Now, the [ToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive) abstract operation is quite long and complex, but I hope that you will believe me that for a string literal it just evaluates to the primitive string value denoted by said string literal. So, *primValue* here is just the primitive string valued denoted by our string literal, which means in particular that the condition in step #2 is false. So, what we are left with, is essentially that we are returning the result of applying the abstract operation ToNumber to the string primitive value of our string literal.

So, if we go back to our current, simplified, definition of the `Number(value)` function:

> 1. Let *prim* be ?ToNumeric(*value*).
> 2. If Type(*prim*) is BigInt, let *n* be (ℝ(*prim*)).
> 3. Otherwise, let *n* be *prim*.
> 4. Return *n*.

We know that the condition in step #2 cannot be true, so we end up with:

> 1. Let *prim* be ?ToNumeric(*value*).
> 2. Let *n* be *prim*.
> 3. Return *n*.

Which we can further simplify to

> 1. Let *prim* be ?ToNumeric(*value*).
> 2. Return *prim*.

or just

> 1. Return ?ToNumeric(*value*).

## Conclusion

We know that ToNumeric, when applied to a string literal is really just ToNumber applied to the string literal value's primitive string value.

Which is basically the same as what we concluded for the case of the *unary prefix `+` operator*.

So, yes, *for this specific case* where the *unary prefix `+` operator* and the *`Number(value)` function* are both applied to a *string literal*, they both end up applying the abstract operation ToNumber to the primitive string value denoted by the string literal.

However, they end up there by following some very different paths.

## "Under the hood"

*But*, that does not mean that the actual code executed at runtime has to look anything like what the specification looks like. The ECMAScript specification, like all specifications, follows an "*as-if*" rule: any implementation is free to do whatever it likes, as long as the result is the same "*as-if*" it had executed the steps in the specification.

You asked whether they are identical "under the hood" and the simple answer is: we don't know, we *can't* know, and we actually *should not be able to know*. That is, after all, the whole point of *abstraction* in software development: that you have a specification which tells you how something behaves and *you don't care how that specification is implemented*.

There is no reason to expect that the way this works "under the hood" in V8 is the same as in SquirrelFish Extreme or SpiderMonkey or GraalJS or IronJS or Narcissus or Rhino or dyn.js or Nashorn or BESEN.

In reality, I expect most modern ECMAScript compilers to optimize most of those steps away, so that the compiled code for

```ecmascript
+"123"
```

and

```ecmascript
Number("123")
```

actually ends up being the same as just

```ecmascript
123
```

In other words, if the compiler can prove that the contents of the string are a valid `number` literal, it will just insert the corresponding primitive number value into the compiled program and never execute all of those steps at runtime.

I even expect that to be true for something like

```ecmascript
const s = "123";

+s

// and

Number(s)
```

and probably even for something like

```ecmascript
let s = "123";

+s

// and

Number(s)
```

If the compiler can prove that `s` has not been re-assigned in between.

However, there is no guarantee that this will actually be the case and there is nothing in the ECMAScript Language Specification that would force an implementation to optimize or to not optimize this, nor is there anything in the spec that would prescribe any particular way of implementing it.

## CAVEAT

All of this is only true if the property `Number` of the global object *actually* refers to the [*`Number` constructor*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor).

If I do something like

```ecmascript
Number = myFunctionWhichDoesSomethingCompletelyDifferent
```

Then all bets are off. This is *not* true for the *unary prefix `+` operator*. ECMAScript does not allow redefining operators, therefore, that one is guaranteed to always behave as prescribed in the specification.